# Minimum lenght of string that match a regex

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

I would like to know if a RegEX engine, before to try to match a regex, checks if the data has a *minimum length* that the regexp requires.
For example the regex "a{1000}" in a data composed of 999 "a", fails.
The result can be obtained avoiding to apply the regex, and only performing some checks to the length of the data (and the minimum of the regex).
So, generically, a RegEX engine performs this kind of tests? In particular I'm interested to know if the *re* module of Python does this.

Comment: Good question. Python uses back-tracking engine, so i guess no it doesn't care about the length. gt and lt operations might come into play though.

Comment: You could find out yourself by measuring the time it takes to apply a regex to input strings of different lengths. If you see a sharp reduction in timings when the string is one character too short that would indicate your regex engine does such a check. (I find that rather unlikely though and you certainly cannot generalize over different regex engines. Especially if expressions get more complex than `a{1000}` it becomes increasingly difficult to tell a minimum length while potential benefits of such a check begin to vanish.)

Comment: Thank's for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In particular I'm interested to know if the re module of Python does this.

A measurement suggests that it does.

```
import re
import timeit
def test(charsInString, charsInRegex):
    regex = re.compile('a{'+str(charsInRegex)+'}')
    string = 'a'*charsInString;
    for i in range(1, 200000):
        regex.match(string)
print(timeit.timeit("test(1, 1)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test(1, 2)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test(1, 5000)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test(4999, 5000)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test(5000, 5000)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test(50000, 5000)", setup="from __main__ import test", number=1))
```

Output:

```
0.9117504503834146
0.8135033788142646
0.819454105947109
0.8154557798237785
15.441637204298287
15.412751909222905
```

And a more complex one:

```
import re
import timeit
def test2(charsInString):
    regex = re.compile('((ab{3,5}c+){5000,6000}d)+e*f')
    string = 'abbbbcc'*charsInString;
    for i in range(1, 100000):
        regex.match(string)
print(timeit.timeit("test2(1)", setup="from __main__ import test2", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test2(3571)", setup="from __main__ import test2", number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("test2(3572)", setup="from __main__ import test2", number=1))
```

Output:

```
0.04918821760123643
0.04305112491748375
60.76094317352544
```